# Connect lan http server over ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, apache-http-server

Consider this scnerio:

apache server listening on 192.168.2.xx. There is no port forwarding setup on router, so this apache instance cannot be accessed from wan.

I have access to same machine over ssh. Router is forwarding port 22 to target machine.

What I want to do is connect a web browser to that apache instance using my ssh connection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  You can use `ssh -L` to accomplish this type of port forwarding.  Presuming your target machine's Apache is listening on 80, do this from your client machine:

```
ssh -L 6789:localhost:80 target-machine
```

Will allow you to talk to your target machine's Apache via `localhost:6789` on the client.  Specifically, you could visit `http://localhost:6789` in your web browser.

Commonly, the `-N` flag is used in conjunction with `ssh -L`, which will prevent SSH from running any remote commands, and just forward the port.